# F statistic vs T statistic

Tags: statistical-significance, anova

I have a variable that I can divide to 3 groups: A, B, C. I want to check if the difference between the groups is significant. Should I use F-STATISTIC or maybe T-STATISTIC of each group vs. the other 2 groups together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use [ANOVA](https://statistics.laerd.com/spss-tutorials/one-way-anova-using-spss-statistics.php) or [Kruskall-Wallis Test](https://statistics.laerd.com/spss-tutorials/kruskal-wallis-h-test-using-spss-statistics.php), depending on the normality of data and other assumptions.

I guess that your null hypothesis is as follows (correct me if I'm wrong):

$$ \mu_A = \mu_B = \mu_C $$

Since you have more than two groups, it will be better to use the mentioned tests than $t$ test. For example, with ANOVA (which uses the $F$ statistics) you perform one test to check if any group is significantly different than the other, but you would need 3 $t$ tests to do the same: A~B, A~C, and B~C.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fast reply, I thought so but wanted to be sure :-)